# Android, размещение объектов в RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Имеется `RelativeLayout` с объектом `CardView`, внутри которого: `ImageView`, `TextView1`, `TextView2`. Требуется эти 3 элемента разместить так, что бы `ImageView` был слева, `TextView1` и `TextView2` - справа от него. `TextView2` должен прижиматься к низу `CardView`, при этом находясь ниже `TextView1`. Сейчас нет вопросов по первым двум элементам, но проблема с 3, он либо прижимается к низу, но перекрывается первым (если там много текста), либо же находится под `TextView1`, и не прижимается к низу. Вот разметка:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBackground">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_card_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_card_view_height"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/news_card_view_photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_date"
                android:textColor="@color/text_labels"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Схема]

Comment: Лучше нарисуйте

Comment: Я бы посоветовал отойти от RelativeLayout, а воспользоваться LinearLayout-ами c применением весов (weigth)

Comment: Нарисовал пример, как нужно.

Comment: Картинку поместите в отдельный контейнер который будет занимать всю высоту item. Относительно его расположите View. Первый на топ, второй на бот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение, добавить: `android:gravity="bottom"`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_date"
            android:textColor="@color/text_labels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_photo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/news_photo"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>
```

Таким образом второй `TextView` всегда прижимается к контейнеру вниз, но если в первом `TextView` текста много, то второй будет размещаться под ним.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно чего вы хотите добиться, но попробуйте

```
android:layout_above="@+id/news_title"
```

перенести в news_title, что бы получилось

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/news_date"
```

Comment: Извините, в спешке не ту версию выложил, исправил. Ваш вариант пробовал, тогда второй TextView перекрывает первый.

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko, могу посоветовать задать жестко высоту второго `TextView`